# How do I consistently identify an audio controller PCI device?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, controller, pci

In my application I retrieve all devices in the machine's PCI space, then filter the audio controller among them in order to use it for some tests. Until now, we used to identify an audio controller by checking its class code and subclass code, previously read in a register in the PCI's configuration space (https://wiki.osdev.org/Intel_High_Definition_Audio). For reference, we could manually confirm that, by looking at the "PCI base class" and "PCI "sub class" properties of the High Definition Audio Controller device in Windows' Device Manager were respectively 4 and 3.

The problem is that we found out that in some machines this doesn't work, as their audio controller's (named Intel(R) Smart Sound Technology (Intel(R) SST) Audio Controller in the Device Manager) PCI base class and PCI sub class properties were actually 4 and 1.

I found some sources that confirm this (https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Class_Codes), but, regardless, how can I identify these cases? Is there a way to know beforehand if the subclass code is supposed to be 3 or 1 (like a system call, or a wmi query), or should I just check for both these codes (if there isn't a PCI device with class code 4 and subclass 1, look for one with class code 4 and subclass code 3). It's a C++ application, in case it's relevant.